# Adding sum to timer

Tags: c#, timer, sum

I would like to know how to create a label that adds `sum + 1` every 5 seconds? I've tried with an if loop but unfortunately it resets one second later.

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
// using system.diagnotics voor stopwatch 
    
namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();                
        }
    
        private Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
           
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            sw.Start();
    
            if (timer1.Enabled == true) { button1.Text = "stop"; }
            else { button1.Text = "false"; sw.Stop(); }
     
        }
    
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int hours = sw.Elapsed.Hours;
            int minutes = sw.Elapsed.Minutes;
            int seconds = sw.Elapsed.Seconds;
            int sum = 0; 
            label1.Text = hours + ":" ;
            if (minutes < 10) { label1.Text += "0" + minutes + ":"; }
            else { label1.Text += minutes + ":"; }
               
            if (seconds < 10) { label1.Text += "0" + seconds ; }
            else { label1.Text += seconds ; }
    
            if (seconds ==5) { sum = sum +=1; }
                    
            label2.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Question has already been answered, but also, you probably don't mean 'sum = sum += 1'. 'sum += 1' is the same thing as 'sum = sum + 1'.

Comment: What is interval of timer tick?

Answer (score 5):

`sum` should be a class field. Also you can use custom format string for elapsed TimeSpan.

```
    int sum = 0;

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // int sum = 0; local variable will be set to zero on each timer tick
        label1.Text = sw.Elapsed.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");

        // btw this will not update sum each five seconds
        if (sw.Elapsed.Seconds == 5) 
            sum++; // same as sum = sum +=1;

        label2.Text = sum.ToString();
    }
```

Your current implementation will increase sum only if current elapsed timeout's second value is five. Which could never happen (depending on your timer interval). If you have timer interval set to 1000 milliseconds, then you can increase sum on each tick, but set `label2.Text = (sum % 5).ToString()`.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to move `sum` out of the timer callback as you are setting it to 0 each time the timer elapses

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private int sum = 0;
    private DateTime lastUpdate;
    private Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}",
                      sw.Elapsed.Hours, sw.Elapsed.Minutes, sw.Elapsed.Seconds);

        if (DateTime.Now >= lastUpdate.AddSeconds(5))
        {
            sum++;
            lastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
            label2.Text = sum.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (timer1.Enabled == true)
        {
            sw.Stop(); 
            button1.Text = "stop";
        }
        else 
        {
            sum = 0;
            lastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            sw.Start();
            button1.Text = "Start"; 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

every time your stopwatch  TICKS,  sum is inside TICK and it will reset and start from

```
int sum=0;
```

so try to make sum variable GLOBAL outside timer1_Tick event and it will continue increasing.